# Set Cursor Position in custom edittext

Tags: android

I have a custom EditText which is empty and I want to set the cursor position using the co-ordinates(x,y) i get from ontouch event. Wherever I touch i should be able to move the cursor to that position and should be able to type the text from there. Help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Selection.setSelection (Spannable text, int index);
```

Comment: setSelection needs some text to be there in the edit text, only then you will have an index. To be more precise, my custom edittext is built for a tablet app which is the only view on whole screen and most importantly it is empty with no text in it. Wherever i touch i should be able to start typing from that point. Hope you got what i am looking for..

Comment: Do you mean that you touch at point x,y and the text starts appearing there? Do you want to move the EditText according to the users touch?  Do you want to fill the EditText with blank characters, and deduce where to start insertion of actual text from the touch point? (I doubt it).

Comment: yes. To be more precise i want to control the cursor inside an empty edittext. Lets say the edittext has 10 lines i would like to type something in 2nd line and 4th line alone. Hope u got it!

Comment: If the EditText has 10 lines, that means it is not empty: it has at least 9 newline characters!  If you want to enter text somewhere other than the beginning of the line, that means you need to pad the lines with blank characters.